# React Native How to filter a Flatlist with more than 3 parameters?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, object, react-native-flatlist

Hello fellow programmers, I'm new & really noob to React Native so I'll quickly summarize the example & the code before we move on..

I'm fetching a list of products from an api and storing it in two arrays: `products[]` and `catalogue[]`

Catalogue array is used to store all the items received from the api. The products array is what will be used by the Flatlist to display the data. When filter is applied, the items in products should get filtered so that the Flatlist with also update the newly filtered data on the screen.

Now here is a simplified one object out of all the objects data that I'm fetching from the api.

```
Object {
  "designNumber": "CHE-S-207 RW",
  "id": 292187,
  "imageUrl": "http://company.shop.org/images/shop/136/4.jpg",
  "itemCategory": "BRACELET",
  "itemStatus": "INSTOCK",
  "itemType": "CHE",
  "quantity": "1",
  "rfidTag": "Item4",
  "shopId": 136,
  "skuNumber": "Item4",
}
```

The main values that I'll be using for my filter from the object's data are `itemStatus`, `itemCategory` and `itemType`.

I'm using these variables in my state object to store the value inside them which I will be picking from the Filter Screen UI using Multiple selection Pickers.

```
state = {
  products: [],
  catalogue: [],
  itemStatus: "", //Binary values. Only one string value for this one
  itemCategory: [], //Multiple values in array
  itemType: [], //Multiple values in array
};
```

Now we come to the main deal. Let's assume I've selected certain values for these filter parameters using the filter screen UI. For example, `itemStatus: "AVAILABLE"`,`itemCategory: ["MENS", "WOMENS", "CORPORATE"]` and `itemType: ["COMMON","UNCOMMON", "SALE", "EXCLUSIVE"]`

So in layman's term, using the UI I selected Available for Status, 3 values for Category and 4 values for Type. Now in the end there is an apply filter button. This is where I call to a function like `filterProducts()` which will take these multiple parameters and filter my Flatlist items accordingly.

Remember, the `catalogue[]` array has the entire data fetched from the api, and the `products[]` array is what getting displayed in the Flatlist. So ideally whatever new filtered data that will be coming from the filter function should update the `products[]` array so that I think will update on the Flatlist as well.

My issue? Every post that I've read on stack and medium always only looks into the Searchbar Search filter example. Which is basically only accepting 1 filter string and then filtering the list.

But what if I have multiple parameters to filter like in the example I'm trying to achieve? what if you have 3 parameters, and each parameter can have multiple values (4 or more) to be considered in filtering. How to apply such a complex level of filtering, and then return the filtered items to my Flatlist?

```
<Button title="Apply Filter" onPress={() => this.filterProducts}/>

filterProducts = () => {
  //Logic to take all the filter parameters and their selected values

  this.state.products = if({/** No filters are applied */}){
    return this.state.catalogue //Return original data
  } else {
    this.state.catalogue.filter({/** Apply complex filter logic here}).map(){
      //return filtered items list
    }
  }
}
```

maybe the logic flow is like this? Except I don't know how to filter a list with these many filter parameters present at once. Any help will greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Update 1:** Based on u/TommyLeong's suggestion, I have updated my code. Here's how my filter function and the logic looks like:

```
state = {
  isFilterActive: false,
  products: [],
  catalogue: [],
  itemStatus: "",
  itemCategory: [],
  itemType: [],
}

//Get data from the api
fetchProducts = aysnc () => {
  //Make the api call and get the response
  const data = await response.json();

  this.setState({
    products: data.data, //Originally show all the data from the api
    catalogue: data.data, //Store all the data from the api
  });
};

//Filter Function
filterProducts = () => {
  console.log("function called", this.state.isFilterActive);
  //Pack all filter data in one query object
  let query = {
    itemStatus: this.state.itemStatus,
    itemCategory: this.state.itemCategory,
    itemType: this.state.itemType,
  };
  console.log("Filter object", Object.entries(query));

  if (this.state.isFilterActive) {
    const filteredData = this.state.catalogue.filter(function (item) {
      return Object.entries(query).every(([key, value]) =>
        value.includes(item[key])
      );
    });
    console.log("Result: Filtered Array", filteredData);
    this.setState({ products: filteredData });
  } else {
    //Return original data is isFilterActive == false
    this.setState({ products: this.state.catalogue });
  }
};

render(){
  return(
    //Contains my views. My Filter screen has a bunch of pickers 
    //and a apply filter button

    <DropDownPicker 
      label="Item Status"
      multipleSelection={true} //More than one values can be selected
      items={/*define my filter values for itemStatus here*/}
      onChangeItem={(item) => {
        this.setState({ itemStatus: item.value});
      }
    />
    <DropDownPicker 
      label="Item Category"
      items={/*define my filter values for itemCategory here*/}
      onChangeItem={(item) => {
        //item here is an array of selected values
        this.setState({ itemCategory: item});
      }
    />
    <DropDownPicker 
      label="Item Type"
      multipleSelection={true} //More than one values can be selected
      items={/*define my filter values for itemType here*/}
      onChangeItem={(item) => {
        //item here is an array of selected values
        this.setState({ itemType: item });
      }
    />
    <Button 
      title="Apply Filter"
      onPress={() => {
        this.setState({ isFilterActive: true }, () =>
          this.filterProducts()
        );
      }}
  )
}
```

Now that my code and logic is fairly clear, let's move onward to the new problem.
the filter logic in the filter function 100% works! *But only when all 3 filter properties have some value selected*

```
//my filter object in the function
let query = {
  itemStatus: this.state.itemStatus,
  itemCategory: this.state.itemCategory,
  itemType: this.state.itemType,
};
```

**Case 1:** console.log when all 3 filter categories have some values selected:

```
Filter object Array [
  Array [
    "itemStatus",
    "INSTOCK",
  ],
  Array [
    "itemCategory",
    Array [
      "MENS",
      "WOMENS",
    ],
  ],
  Array [
    "itemType",
    Array [
      "COMMON",
      "SALE"
    ],
  ],
]

Result: Filtered Array Array[
  Object: {
    //first item matching all 3 filter criteria
  },
  Object: {
    //2nd item matching all 3 filter criteria
  },
  Object: {
    //3rd item matching all 3 filter criteria
  },
]
```

**Case 2:** console.log when no value is selected for any one of the 3 filter criterias. For this case, I pick itemType i.e. itemType[] is blank.

```
Filter object Array [
  Array [
    "itemStatus",
    "INSTOCK",
  ],
  Array [
    "itemCategory",
    Array [
      "MENS",
      "WOMENS",
    ],
  ],
  Array [
    "itemType",
    Array [], //Array is blank here because no filter 
              //values were picked for itemType
  ],
]

Result: Filtered Array Array [] //No items returned to me, Flatlist becomes empty
```

I certainly know that the issue is in this filter logic, but I can't scratch my head off, why the filter is not working when there are undefined values for one of the 3 criteria.. **and most importantly, again idk how to fix it :(**

```
//Current filter Logic
if (this.state.isFilterActive) {
    const filteredData = this.state.catalogue.filter(function (item) {
      return Object.entries(query).every(([key, value]) =>
        value.includes(item[key])
      );
    });
    console.log("Result: Filtered Array", filteredData);
    this.setState({ products: filteredData });
  } else {
    //Return original data is isFilterActive == false
    this.setState({ products: this.state.catalogue });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I will tackle..

1. Create a variable call `hasFilterApply` to store boolean value on whether user has applied any filter. You need to set boolean back to FALSE when remove all the filters from UI.
2. Every time before filtering, I will decide which array (catalogues/products) to do filter based on `hasFilterArray`. If true, means I should continue to use `this.state.products` as it contains the latest filtered product list.
3. When rendering, check again whether `hasFilterApply` is TRUE. If yes, then render `this.state.products` otherwise just render `this.state.catalgoues`

```
this.state = {
    hasFilterApply: false,      // update hasFilterApply to TRUE when one or more filter is applied, set to FALSE when no filter is applied
    catalogues: [],             // keep original response
    products: []                // this will be the final render product list
}

/*
* Assuming this is how your catalgoues will be
const catalogues = [{"designNumber":"CHE-S-207 A","id":1,"imageUrl":"http://company.shop.org/images/shop/136/4.jpg","itemCategory":"BRACELET","itemStatus":"AVAILABLE","itemType":"EXCLUSIVE","quantity":"1","rfidTag":"Item1","shopId":1,"skuNumber":"Item1",},{"designNumber":"CHE-S-207 B","id":2,"imageUrl":"http://company.shop.org/images/shop/136/4.jpg","itemCategory":"MENS","itemStatus":"NO","itemType":"SALE","quantity":"1","rfidTag":"Item2","shopId":2,"skuNumber":"Item2",},{"designNumber":"CHE-S-207 C","id":3,"imageUrl":"http://company.shop.org/images/shop/136/4.jpg","itemCategory":"WOMENS","itemStatus":"AVAILABLE","itemType":"UNCOMMON","quantity":"1","rfidTag":"Item3","shopId":3,"skuNumber":"Item3",},{"designNumber":"CHE-S-207 D","id":4,"imageUrl":"http://company.shop.org/images/shop/136/4.jpg","itemCategory":"CORPORATE","itemStatus":"AVAILABLE","itemType":"COMMON","quantity":"1","rfidTag":"Item4","shopId":4,"skuNumber":"Item4",},{"designNumber":"CHE-S-207 E","id":5,"imageUrl":"http://company.shop.org/images/shop/136/4.jpg","itemCategory":"MENS","itemStatus":"AVAILABLE","itemType":"COMMON","quantity":"1","rfidTag":"Item5","shopId":5,"skuNumber":"Item5",},]
*/

getFromAPI = async () => {
    const catalogues = await getCatalogues();
    this.setState({ catalogues })
}

filterStatus = (filterValue) => {
    const latestList = hasFilterApply ? this.state.products : this.state.catalogues;
    const newList = []

    latestList.filter((product)=>{
      if(product.itemStatus === filterValue){
        newList.push(product)
      }
    }

    this.setState({ products: newList })
}

filterCategory = (filterValue) => {
    const latestList = hasFilterApply ? this.state.products : this.state.catalogues;
    const newList = []

    latestList.filter((product)=>{
      if(product.itemCategory === filterValue){
        newList.push(product)
      }
    }

    this.setState({ products: newList })
}

filterType = (filterValue) => {
    const latestList = hasFilterApply ? this.state.products : this.state.catalogues;
    const newList = []

    latestList.filter((product)=>{
      if(product.itemType === filterValue){
        newList.push(product)
      }
    }

    this.setState({ products: newList })
}

renderMyProducts = () => {
    // At the end before you decide render the products, you should know which ARRAY (catalgoues/products) should be passed to your component.
    // Do checking on whehter "hasFilterApply" is TRUE or false. If false, then pass catalgoues, otherwise pass products to your  component.
}

render(){
    return(
        // render your components
    )
}
```

Comment: A very interesting implementation for filter I see. So do I have to really make 3 filter functions for one of the each filter parameter or can it be achieved using a single filter function like filterProducts() I mentioned in my original post. like a single function but it takes more than one parameters. Just curious for any other implementation methods?

Comment: Unless you know what needs to be filter, otherwise you are depending on a very dynamic list of array and the filter parameters. Of course you can shorten the filter by doing so `catalogues.filter(prod => prod.itemStatus === 'AVAILABLE' && prod.itemType === 'COMMON')` when you know exactly what filtering you want to apply, filter parameter can be a variable.

Comment: Yes, I know what I'm filtering. Like I mentioned in the post, there are only 3 parameters that I'll be dealing with: `itemStatus`, `itemCategory` and `itemType`. There values are the only things that will be changing.

Regarding your last comment, what if my itemType array has more than one values passed in it? for example `itemType["COMMON", "SALE", "EXCLUSIVE"]`. then how will this `catalogues.filter(prod => prod.itemStatus === 'AVAILABLE' && prod.itemType === 'COMMON')` expression change?

Comment: Unless you are filtering only each `itemStatus`, `itemCategory` and `itemType` once. Then you may use the following `catalogues.filter(prod => prod.itemStatus === itemStatus && prod.itemType === itemType && prod.itemCategory === itemCategory)`. But there may be event you want to filter two kind of `itemType` hence you need to find a way to append `prod.itemType === itemType` into your validation.

Comment: My answer provided is not complete to fix your code directly, as you have have to cater for case whereby user UN-filter either `itemStatus`, `itemCategory` or `itemType`. Once filter is remove, you should use `catalogues` to do filtering again, as that was the source of truth before any filtering.

Comment: Hey, I've updated my question with new code. It also now contains the current filter logic that I'm using. But I'm still facing an issue. Will you please take a look at the updated question?